# A program to map keys just for a certain executable?

Tags: windows, mapping, keyboard-layout

If you like to launch a game that has uncomfortable key combination, is there a program to map better keys just for that game without affecting the entire system?

For the sake of example, let's say your game's executable is notepad.exe and you'd like the letter `/` to actually type `\`, but only inside Notepad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Direct answers:

1. [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) in [here](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?p=410539#p410539).
2. [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com) in [here](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/54583-remap-shortcuts-only-for-specific-application/?do=findComment&comment=413685).

Answer (score 0):

[AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com) can do this. See [this thread in the AHK forums](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=23356)

Comment: Thanks, but I found a more direct [answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/79960/57778) there.